# Random number generator in C#

Tags: c#, random

I don't know if it is any good. I've never done this, thus, I noticed it is kinda slow.

Can you suggest improvements? I may use it in actual software in the future.

```
private int secgen(int minvalue, int maxvalue)
    {
        Func<int, int, int, int> modular = (a, b, mod) => 
        {
            long rem;
            Math.DivRem((long)a + (long)b, (long)mod, out rem);

            if (rem < minvalue)
                rem += minvalue;

            return (int)rem;
        };


        byte[] entropyBytes = new byte[257];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        rng.GetBytes(entropyBytes);
        int value = entropyBytes[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 257; i++) 
        {
            value = modular(value, entropyBytes[i], maxvalue);


        }

        //MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: What do you need the random numbers for ?

Comment: "good" has different meanings when it comes to random number generators. Uniformity, Independence, Replication, Cycle length, Speed, Memory usage, etc. Depends what you're going for.

Comment: The algorithm does not work correct: For instance: MinValue: 10000 and MaxValue: 10010 produces values like: 18752, 19675, ....

Comment: @JanDotNet Thanks for catching that. I used a lazy method adding MinValue to the remainder

Answer (score 1):

You may improve performance:

I would use the `modulo` operator instead of a function call you aren't benefiting from 100%. `Math.DivRem` returns a value (quotient) that you don't use. Same result:

```
var rem = a + b % mod;
```

Saves you a few unboxing operations and method call

```
Func<int, int, int, int> modular = (a, b, mod) =>
{
    var rem = a + b % mod;

    if (rem < minvalue)
        rem += minvalue;

    return rem;
};
```

Saves half the time? http://pastebin.com/XTaLCQh4

Comment: Thanks, I've always had trouble finding the right operators in the language.